# Joining dBase (*.dbf) table to Coverage?

Tags: arcpy, attribute-joins, dbf, esri-coverage-format

I have a dbf table and a polygon coverage. How do I join and save the joined data to the coverage without exporting to feature class and then re-creating a coverage in python? I have been looking at playing with info tables, but there is not much info out there on it.

So, if I, in arcpy, use the joinItem, I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "G:/Projects/P747/3_Landbase/LB1/Final_Scripts/V_2/Step_04.py",
>   line 36, in 
>       arcpy.JoinItem_COVG(Polygon, Table, Polygon, "MKEY")   File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Coverage Tools.tbx",
>   line 2091, in JoinItem
>        arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Error opening ELIMINATETABLE.DBF Failed to execute (JoinItem).

```
import arcinfo, arcpy, os, sys, gc, datetime, time
from arcpy import env

print 'Starting....'

env.OverWriteOutput = True
env.qualifiedFieldNames = False
arcpy.SetProduct("ArcInfo")

ts = time.time()
st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
print 'Start time = ' + st

tbx = arcpy.ImportToolbox(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Coverage Tools.tbx", "COVG")

env.workspace = "G:\\Projects\\P747\\3_Landbase\\LB1\\multiunion\\m_20150128\\"
Table = "\\\\silver\\clients\\Projects\\P747\\3_Landbase\\LB1\\Eliminate\\El_20150122\\EliminateTable.dbf"
FCLayer = "\\\\silver\\clients\\Projects\\P747\\3_Landbase\\LB1\\TEMP\\\FCLayer.lyr"
TableLayer = "\\\\silver\\clients\\Projects\\P747\\3_Landbase\\LB1\\TEMP\\\TableLayer.lyr"

print 'Loaded Data....'

if arcpy.Exists(FCLayer):
    arcpy.Delete_management(FCLayer)
if arcpy.Exists(TableLayer):
    arcpy.Delete_management(TableLayer)

print 'Deleted Existing Layers....'

for Coverage in arcpy.ListFiles("*_Union"):

    print 'Working on ' + Coverage

    Polygon = env.workspace + "\\" + Coverage + "\\polygon"
    arcpy.JoinItem_COVG(Polygon, Table, Polygon, "MKEY")
    break
```

What does "support is stopped"? Will I still be able to use my coverage tools?

Comment: That would have to be done in workstation; in ArcGis desktop no tool (that I know of) will 'save as' a coverage. You would have to import the DBF to INFO table then RELATE ADD... it's been a while..

Answer (score 2):

I have never used the Coverage Tools but am very familiar with ArcInfo Workstation and AML but I think you should be able to accomplish this in a two step process:

1. [Table To Table (Conversion)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001200000027000000)

> This tool can convert input tables to dBASE (.dbf), geodatabase
>   (personal, file, or SDE), or INFO tables.

2. [Join Info Tables (Coverage)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00130000004q000000)

> Joins the item definitions and values of two tables based on a shared
>   item. Joining involves appending items (fields) of one table to those
>   of another through an attribute or item common to both tables. A join
>   is usually used to attach more attributes to the attribute table of a
>   geographic layer.

The above would be the ArcGIS Desktop equivalent of this ARC/INFO procedure:

1. DBASEINFO
2. JOINITEM

I would not advocate anyone continuing to use coverage format.

Comment: Oddly enough Join Info Tables is arcpy.JoinItem_arc... the syntax is similar. From memory it was safe to JOINITEM where in_info_table =  out_info_table as all the necessary items and rows are maintained.

Comment: FYI "ArcGIS for Desktop Advanced: Requires ArcInfo Workstation installed" support is stopped after 10.2

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Yes - I usually (always?) joined items from the join table onto the original.

Comment: @Mapperz, what's this about needing to install Workstation? I'm using an Advanced license but haven't installed Workstation since v9.x; I'm not sure I remember enough ArcINFO commands to do anything meaningful. ArcInfo workstation requires an advanced license but I don't recall anything about it being the other way around.

Comment: Licensing Information states it http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001300000026000000